# How to serialize Inherited properties?

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

I do have a 3rd party library that exposes an abstract class for some messaging, like this.

```
    [ProtoContract]
    public abstract class MessageBase
    {
        [ProtoMember(101)]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public abstract int Type { get; }
    }
```

now in my application I do create a derived class from it

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(999, typeof(MessageBase))]
public class Echo : MessageBase
{
    public const int ID = 1;



    public override int Type
    {
        get { return ID; }
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

but when I try to (de)/serialize the property ErrorMessage from base class is ignored. Here is the code that simulates the situation.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Echo echo = new Echo{Message = "Some message", ErrorMessage = "XXXXX"};
                ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(ms, echo);



                //reset ms
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                Echo echo1 = (Echo)ProtoBuf.Serializer.NonGeneric.Deserialize(typeof(Echo), ms);
                Debug.Assert(echo.ErrorMessage == echo1.ErrorMessage, "Must be the same");
            }
```

I did read about ProtoInclude, but it looks like is ignored in my derived class.

I cannot change the base class, I do not have the source code for the 3rd party library.

I might have about 100 derived classes from the MessageBase.

I have to use the NonGeneric version of deserialization, cause I know the type only at run-time.

How do I solve my problem?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ProtoIncludeAttribute is misplaced. The base-type needs to be told about the derived types, not the other way around.

Add ProtoIncludeAttribute to MessageBase, and remove it from the subclass (unless of course the subclass itself has more subclasses)

---

As explained in comments; if the base-type cannot be edited, it must be configured at runtime. That can be done as follows (see also a test based on the one from the comments):

```
[Test]
public void AddSubtypeAtRuntime()
{
    var messageBase = RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(MessageBase)];
    // this could be explicit in code, or via some external config file
    // that you process at startup
    messageBase.AddSubType(10, typeof(Echo)); // would need to **reliably** be 10
    messageBase.AddSubType(11, typeof(Foo));
    messageBase.AddSubType(12, typeof(Bar)); // etc

    // test it...
    Echo echo = new Echo { Message = "Some message", ErrorMessage = "XXXXX" };
    MessageBase echo1;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Serializer.NonGeneric.Serialize(ms, echo);
        ms.Position = 0;
        echo1 = (MessageBase)Serializer.NonGeneric.Deserialize(
                                   typeof(MessageBase), ms);
    }
    Assert.AreSame(echo.GetType(), echo1.GetType());
    Assert.AreEqual(echo.ErrorMessage, echo1.ErrorMessage);
    Assert.AreEqual(echo.Message, ((Echo)echo1).Message);
}
```

Comment: as I told in my message, I cannot alter the base class, I don't have the source code for it. 
But even so, what if I have 1000 derived classes, shall I add 1000 includes? Doesn't sounds pretty right to me.

Comment: @Eugen sorry, I missed that part. In that case you will need to tell the runtime instead - I'll add an example when I'm at a PC (on mobile right now) - but to emphasize: yes, that (configuring the relationship between base and derived from the base) is right - and it is exactly what you would need to do for any similar category ("contract based") of serializer, including XmlSerializer and DataContractSerializer. If I may posit: the bigger question is why you need 1000 subclasses. That sounds unusually high (it should still cope, though)

Comment: oh man, that really sucks. I switched to proto over JSON to gain speed, and instead gained troubles. Never had such issues with json serializers, somehow they know about all the properties for a given type including those form base classes. well anyhow, thx for clarification, I'll have to switch to another serializer now.

I need 1000 classes, just to make the conversation between tcp server/client very type safe. So I have a message class for any type of request/response.

Comment: @Eugen presumably your Json serializer adds additional text about the type. Protobuf-net tries to avoid that, for efficiency. It does have a feature close to this, but it does not currently work nicely with inheritance. I could probably fix that fairly easily, if you don't need it "today"

Comment: @eugen hmm... Scratch that: even if the dymanic-type feature supported this, the model would still need to be configured the same way, so that wouldn't add anything - probably why I never did it in the first place!

Comment: @Eugen fundamentally, the problem here is that protobuf-net simply doesn't want include type names / field names. That is *why* it is efficient, but it also places certain restrictions in terms of understanding things it didn't know already. Specifically, if you have fields labelled as 1, 2 and 3 - and you receive a 47... What do you do with that? How would you know how to map it to a type that you've never heard of?

Comment: when I send data over the wire I do prefix it with a number that tells me on receiver's side the Type received. (using a Dictionary<int,Type>) for this. I was thinking since I do pass the Type value the Proto would go over all its public properties including the inherited once, and map them to the Tags I used in ProtoMember attribute, can't really see what's the issue here.

Comment: My goal was to achieve the same functionality like here

Echo echo = new Echo { Message = "Some message", ErrorMessage = "XXXXX" };
            string s = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(echo);

            Echo echo1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Echo>(s);

            Debug.Assert(echo.ErrorMessage == echo1.ErrorMessage, "Must be the same");


which is working as expected.